# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 on a USB drive

Tags: live-usb, startup-disk-creator

I tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 on a USB drive using Startup Disk Creator, but I get this error message:

```
An uncaught exception was raised:
E:Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf:4: Extra junk at end of file
```

What does it mean? How can I install Ubuntu on my USB drive?

Comment: What OS are you doing this from?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the apt.conf has the larger size than it was expected. So please remove the apt.conf and rerun apt and the apt.conf will be recreated. If it still does not help, check your Internet connection and then open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get purge apt
sudo apt-get install apt
```